# How do I teach my students the difference between ‘after’ and ‘next’?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

[image]How do I teach my students the difference between ‘[after](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=definition+after)’ and ‘[next](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=definition+next)’?

The real *using* of each of them.

**after**
1. in the time following (an event or another period of time).

**next**
1. (of a time) coming immediately after the time of writing or speaking.

For example,

> 1. After Monday I'm going back to school.
> 2. Next Monday I'm going back to school.

And

> 1. I'm going back to school after.
> 2. I'm going back to school next.

If all four sentences are correct, does this mean *next* and *after* are interchangeable? What exceptions are there?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems they're having? What are some example sentences they get wrong?

Comment: why we sometimes use next Ex: Guess what I did next?
not "before"?

Comment: If your saying *guess what I did next?* It's clear that something happened before and you want to say what happened after that. If you say *guess what I did before* It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I'm confused... you can say "Guess what I did after that?"... and it means the same thing as "Guess what I did next?"

Comment: sorry I mean " after" not " before"

like this :
 
why we sometimes use next Ex: Guess what I did next? not "after"?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean the same one of them has less Grammarly and I need to know when each of them coming and there forms also.

Comment: Why do you think that "Guess what I did after that?" is incorrect?

Comment: Because what I know that after is wrong to be here and it has its uses

Comment: I am a native English speaker and I am telling you that it **is not wrong**.

Comment: I would show u a paper that was ordered from me to give an experiment lesson.
How can I send it to you?

Comment: **Next** means the **adjacent** thing you did when in a sequence, so *something* that comes **next** also comes **after**. "**B**" comes next after "**A**". *Something* that comes *after* means it comes later in a sequence of things, but is not necessarily **next**. "**C**" comes **after** "**A**", and is **next** after "**B**"; "**B**" is **next** after "**A**"

Comment: @Peter that doesn't mean they **can't** be sequential... "B" comes after "A" is perfectly fine... And doesn't **necessarily** imply that they are not sequential.

Comment: It's **after that**; "that" could be  *breakfast* or  any noun e.g. *a movie* You don't normally say "I went out after" or "After we took the bus home" But "*I went out* ***after breakfast***". "***After the movie*** *we took the bus home*"

Comment: I have a paper I would to send it for anyone here to see that using of " after" instead of "next" is wrong

Comment: @ms.crystal take a screenshot of the relevant paragraph and upload it to a picture sharing site like imgur or tinypic

Comment: I put the screenshot

Comment: ms.crystal - @Catija is correct.  _"Guess what I did after that"_ would be fine.  As Nachtara explains below, _after_ is a preposition, and needs an object.  _"That"_ serves as the object of the preposition.

Comment: yeah, Now I understand

Comment: BTW - The explanation in the screenshot you posted is poor.  We do use "after" in sequences all the time.

Comment: not me this is a book  called: Companion for an institution that studies this type of English subjects.

Answer (score 5):

After and Next are not interchangeable.

Your examples:

> 1. "After Monday, I'm going back to school."
> 2. "Next Monday, I'm going back to school."

"After" in this sentence implies that you are not going to school Monday, but you will later. Using "next" here means you're going to go to school when Monday occurs.

> 1. "I'm going back to school after"
> 2. "I'm going back to school next"

The first example here is grammatically wrong. It's not a complete sentence. "After" is a preposition, and prepositions need to be followed by a noun, unless it's implied. The response to "I'm going back to school after" would be "After what?".

Next would be correct here. This sentence is implying the next action to be completed is going back to school.

Comment: +1 _"I'm going back to school next._ could also refer to sequencing of students.  _"My family is so poor, my three siblings and I all had to drop out of school to help at home.  Daddy got a new job though, and my sisters have been going to school for the last month.  I am going back to school next.  Roger was never all that good at studying anyways, so he might not return."_

Comment: "After" is also more likely to be used when the exact time of the future triggering event is potentially unknown but definitely singular. "After Monday" is somewhat awkward, because there are many Mondays; "after the baby is born" or "after I get a new car" are more common.

Answer (score -1):

Both the words **next** and **after** have similar meaning, but their usage is different. **next** means **immediately following something** but **after** can mean any time afterward without caring about the order.

Both **next** and **after** are preposition. Whereas **next** is an intransitive preposition, **after** is transitive except in cases where it has an implied elliptical complement. **next** can also be an adjective.

> **After** *lunch* we left for a movie. [Preposition **after** takes a complement *lunch*]
>
> Look that is the thief running, and the police chasing **after**. [Here the preposition **after** doesn't have a complement, but it has an implied elliptical complement like this *...and the police chasing after him (the thief)]

But we the preposition **next** is an intransitive, that is it doesn't allow any complement.

> - We left for a movie **next** *lunch*. [INCORRECT]
>
> What are planning to do **next**? [CORRECT]

In constructions like *next day*, *next Monday* it's an adjective. It's actually an NP that can act like an adverbial. Lerson called it *bare NP adverbial*.

> We will be back to school next Monday.
>
> We will be back to school after Monday.

Though the sentences above syntactically look similar they mean different. While the one with *after* means that we can be back to school any day that comes Monday. But the last sentence says that we will be back to school on Monday that comes next.

Hope this helps. I wish I could reword the last paragraph, but I can't think of any other way to write it right now.

---

- The reason to consider **next** as a preposition, not an adverb:

  1. After copular *is* it's incorrect to place an adverb, but a preposition can comfortably occur there.

> He *is* **in** the middle of a task. 
>   He *is* **in**. 
>   He *is* **subsequently** [INCORRECT]

But we can write the following -

> Our performance *is* **next**.

2. There are certain adverbs (*e.g* right, straight) that can only modify a preposition.

> Stand *right* **next** to me.

Comment: Next and after do not have the same meaning. Next means immediately following, after just means subsequently. Elsa took her turn and I went next. Nica's turn was next after mine. Both Nica and I took our turns after Elsa.

Comment: The use of "next" as a standalone  preposition without "to" beside it is extremely archaic, transitive, and doesn't match your examples.  In a sentence like _"I will answer next"_, it is an adverb modifying _answer._  In modern usage it is only a preposition as part of _"next to,"_ in which case it is transitive:  _"The dog is next to the cat."_